# error encountered in java servelt package project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I developed a JSP project on my PC using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 and SQL workbench. I exported that project on my laptop and added all the required libraries, but it is showing this error whenever I try to access the database linked to my project. The project is made using my SQL database. The error is shown in the image below!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPMkZ.jpg)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and include the error as text, so that search engines can find it. Also provide your code as a [mcve] in the question, so that others can reproduce the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The image attached shows a NoClassDefFoundError. It means that the library for aspectj.jar is not there in your application classpath.